# MongoDB: project element present inside array inside of array inside an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongo and I need only a certain element of it.

The Structure of the document is something like this:

```
{
  outerArray: [
    {
      innerArray: [
        {
          elem: val1
        },
        {
          elem: val2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      innerArray: [
        {
          elem: val3
        },
        {
          elem: val1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I just need the value of `elem` from this collection. Also, getting unique values is also a plus but not necessary.

**Desired Output :**

```
{
  elem: [
    val1,
    val2,
    val3
  ]
}
```

I have tried with projection and aggregation but not able to succeed.
I am using Mongo 3.4.6.

Comment: are the keys for inner arrays `innerArray` are constant or dynamic ?

Comment: the keys of `innerArray` are constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MongoDB's [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Projecting only `elem` as you just need values of `elem` field which reduces size of doc for further stages */
  {
    $project: { _id: 0, elem: "$outerArray.innerArray.elem" }
  },
  /** Re-create `elem` array field with only unique values by iterating on initial array & pushing uniques */
  {
    $project: {
      elem: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$elem",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $setUnion: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lpGtI5l0vVr)

Answer (score 0):

You need [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html).

Look at [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html). Which I have used to build this aggregation pipeline.

```
db.i.aggregate([{ $unwind: "$outerArray" }, { $unwind: "$outerArray.innerArray" }, { $group: { _id: "$_id", "elem":  { $addToSet: "$outerArray.innerArray.elem" } } } ])
```